# Transformable attribute in Core Data not export/sync with iCloud

Tags: swift, core-data, encrypted-core-data-sql

I am using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`.
All data sync in iCloud. And when uninstalled the app, its sync correctly.

However, it's required to encrypt sensitive data. I made my password attribute Transformable.  Thus work fine locally. However when I delete the app. Install again. All other attributes(String, Int) sync correctly but transformable attribute does not export/synced.

Here is my Model [image]

```
public class EmployeeEntity: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged public var password: NSObject?

    @NSManaged public var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged public var lastName: String?
    @NSManaged public var idNumber: String?
    @NSManaged public var modifiedDate: Date?
    @NSManaged public var password: String?
    @NSManaged public var title: String?

    static var entityName: String { return "EmployeeEntity" }
}


extension EmployeeEntity {

    static func getListItemFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<EmployeeEntity>{
        let request = EmployeeEntity.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<EmployeeEntity>
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdDate", ascending: false)]
        return request
    }
}

import UIKit

class EncryptionTransformer: ValueTransformer {

    override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool{
        return true
    }
    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        return NSData.self
    }
    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any?{
        guard let date = value as? String else {return nil}

        return date.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedData()
    }

    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any?{
        guard let data = value as? String, let decoded = Data(base64Encoded: data) else {return nil}

        return String(data: decoded, encoding: .utf8)
    }
}
```

**Do you have any idea why Transformable value not saved/sync from iCloud?**

Comment: Since you are already handling the conversion between String/Data, have you tried using a 'Binary' data type (i.e. Data), instead of 'Transformable'?

Comment: No. I did not check with this. Because for security reason I have to use transformable(as it is hide in sqlite coredata)

Comment: Is there a reason you declare the `password` attribute twice in your `NSManagedObject` subclass for `Employee Entity`? As far as I understand the second will hold. Also if you refer to the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/reading_cloudkit_records_for_core_data) you’ll notice that both string and transformable attributes can be stored as `CKAsset` by CloudKit.

Comment: First I started with password attribute String, Then I chnaged it to transformable. Does it affect twice which you mentioned?